# How to set the mask based on the different values of lengths using C program

Tags: c, bitmask

In a function I have to pass the bitlength and based on the bit length the mask will be set. For example here is my part of program

```
if(length == 8)
    mask = 0xff;
if(length == 7)
    mask = 0x7f;
if(length == 12)
    mask = 0x3ff;
if(length == 16)
    mask = 0xffff;
```

How can I use some loop statements to set the mask as the length varies from 1 to 16?
It would be great if someone helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: shift a '1' into the mask register for each Bit in the length-register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a value of zero.  Then for every bit in the mask, shift left by 1 then OR a 1 bit at the end.

```
uint16_t mask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    mask <<= 1;
    mask |= 1;
}
```

Comment: come on - loop for this task?? . `uint32_t mask = (1 << length) -1;`  or `uint16_t mask = length == 16 ? 0xffff : (1 << length) -1;`

Answer (score 2):

> How to set the mask based on the different values of lengths using C program?

Shift 1u by `n`, then subtract 1.  No loop needed.  Best to use *unsigned* types and guard against a large `length` with a mask to insure no *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
#define UINT_WIDTH 32
unsigned length = foo();
unsigned mask = (1u << (length & (UINT_WIDTH - 1)) - 1u;
```

> How can I use some loop statements to set the mask as the length varies from 1 to 16?

This works well for `[1 ... UINT_WIDTH]`.

---

If using fixed width types like `uint16_t`, then set the `..._WIDTH` mask to 16.

For portable code, `UINT_WIDTH` needs to be consistent with `unsigned`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#if UINT_MAX == 0xFFFF
  #define UINT_WIDTH 16
#elif UINT_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFF
  #define UINT_WIDTH 32
#elif UINT_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 
  #define UINT_WIDTH 64
#else
  // Very rare
  #error TBD code
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following:

```
uint16_t mask = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    mask |= (1 << i);
```

For each iteration of the loop, you or `|` your `mask` with a bit shifted by `i` position to the left.